# How do I capture and insert the User Name during from Login or CreateUserWizard to a second database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using Visual Web Developer 2012 VB.net.  From the standard CreateUserWizard  / login during the insert to standard `ASPNETDB.mdf` I need to capture the `UserName` and the `Email address` and inserted in to a separate `ABC` `SQL database` into the membership table .  The idea is that after the user crates the log in account then can complete the membership application in the `ABC` database where the User Name / Email Address, identifies him.  Both databases `(ASNETDB.MDF and ABC)` are part of the same web application.  I intend to use the Session and Response. Redirect to transfer user identity to the Membership Page. 
Anyway 
I am new with Visual Basic. Net and the latest dot net. I would greatly appreciate help with my programming issue. Thanks in advance!!!